# How do I enter a value in a text box using AutoIt?

Tags: autoit

I have two text boxes and one button. How do I enter a value into a text box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to the button using [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: I have tried with ControlstText is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's that easy for an example:

```
$gui = GUICreate("Test GUI", 640, 280)
$input = GUICtrlCreateInput("Input field", 10, 10, 620, 20)
$edit = GUICtrlCreateEdit("Edit Control with Text", 10, 40, 620, 200)
$button = GUICtrlCreateButton("Button", 10, 250, 620, 20)

GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

Sleep(2000)

ControlSetText("Test GUI", "", $input, "New text for the input")
ControlSetText("Test GUI", "", $edit, "New text for the edit... with some bla bla bla...")
Sleep(500)
ControlClick("Test GUI", "", $button)
Sleep(500)
ControlFocus("Test GUI", "", $input)

Sleep(4000)

ControlSetText("Test GUI", "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]", "New text for the input, referenced as Edit1")
ControlSetText("Test GUI", "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:2]", "New text for the edit..., referenced as Edit2 with some bla bla bla...")
Sleep(500)
ControlClick("Test GUI", "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]")
Sleep(500)
ControlFocus("Test GUI", "", $input)

Sleep(4000)
```

And besides, your english is quite unclear, you should put a little more effort in your questions ;-)

If you want to find out, what `"[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]"` you must use, try out the "AutoIt v3 Window Info" [tool](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm). And start reading some of the pretty good documentation. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

1. You can use ControlSend function as below:

   ControlSend("Window Title", "", "", "MyUsername{TAB}MyPassword{ENTER}")
2. It can also be done by using Send function:

   Send("username")
   Send("{TAB}")
   Send("password")
   Send("{ENTER}")

Answer (score -2):

```
AutoItX x = new AutoItX(); 
x.controlSend("Login Station - Third party App","","","StringToBeEntered",false);
```

Comment: Do not write only code while answering, prefer to write some explanation.